# How to make a div scroll to the bottom of its container then scroll back up when it's done in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got multiple columns in a table that exceed the screen height while some do not, so I'm trying to get the overflowing columns to auto scroll down to show all data, then scroll back up, repeatedly.

I tried a recursive function like:

```
function colScroll() {
    let el = document.getElementById("col");
    if (el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop === el.clientHeight) {
      el.scrollBy(0,-1);
    } else {
      el.scrollBy(0,1);
    }
    let scrolldelay = setTimeout(colScroll,10);
  }
```

However I get the Maximum call stack size exceeded error for that. Works on non-React code, but not with React.

EDIT

Full code.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import DataCard from './DataCard';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './app.scss';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }

    this.scrollColumn = this.scrollColumn.bind(this);
  }

  scrollColumn() {
    let el = document.getElementById("col-pending-auth");
    if (el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop === el.clientHeight) {
      el.scrollBy(0,-1);
    } else {
      el.scrollBy(0,1);
    }
    scrolldelay = setTimeout(scrollColumn, 10);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = new URL("example.com");
    const params = {};
    url.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();

    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({data: res.data});
        console.log(res.data);
      });

      this.scrollColumn();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="table-responsive">
        <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th scope="col">Proposed</th>
          <th scope="col">Pending Auth</th>
          <th scope="col">Rejected</th>
          <th scope="col">Approved</th>
          <th scope="col">Pending Review</th>
          <th scope="col">Plant Reviewed</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div className="scroll-container" id="col-proposed">
                {
                  this.state.data.map((item, idx) => {
                    if (item.ID === "0") {
                      return <DataCard cardData={item} key={idx} />
                    }
                  })
                }
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div className="scroll-container" id="col-pending-auth">
                {
                  this.state.data.map((item, idx) => {
                    if (item.ID === "1") {
                      return <DataCard cardData={item} key={idx} />
                    }
                  })
                }
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div className="scroll-container" id="col-rejected">
                {
                  this.state.data.map((item, idx) => {
                    if (item.ID === "3") {
                      return <DataCard cardData={item} key={idx} />
                    }
                  })
                }
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div className="scroll-container" id="col-approved">
                {
                  this.state.data.map((item, idx) => {
                    if (item.ID === "2") {
                      return <DataCard cardData={item} key={idx} />
                    }
                  })
                }
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div className="scroll-container" id="col-pending-review">
                {
                  this.state.data.map((item, idx) => {
                    if (item.ID === "5") {
                      return <DataCard cardData={item} key={idx} />
                    }
                  })
                }
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div className="scroll-container" id="col-plant-reviewed">
                {
                  this.state.data.map((item, idx) => {
                    if (item.ID === "4") {
                      return <DataCard cardData={item} key={idx} />
                    }
                  })
                }
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

It's just a one page table displaying info pulled in from an API. Meant to be displayed on a TV screen, so trying to get anything that overflows to auto scroll.

Comment: Hi Bailey Charlton, welcome StackOverflow.  
Can you post [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because not enough context is provided.

Comment: A full example would be better, but the first thing I notice is that you are using document.getElementById which can be dangerous in the context of React. Look at using a ref instead https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @RipTheJacker I only have document.getElementById in there because I'm converting a vanilla JS file to React, haven't gotten to changing to refs. Will post the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare a variable in `state` that counts the amount of scrolls. Then using `this.setState()` you can add one every time it the function is called. If it is a multiple of 2 , then scroll down. Else scroll up. To check if it is a multiple of 2, use `% 2`.

## CSS approach

You can also do this without React. When the user hovers over the non-overflowing columns, all of the columns will move downward. Once the user gets his mouse out of the non-overflowing columns then the columns will move up. I don't know if this is what you want or not.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to make those scroll containers into React.Component's and move your scroll code there. This way you only will the scroll code when the component is updated, which is whenever a child element is added and not need a setTimeout. Here is what that would look like:

```js
import React, { Component, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

const ScrollColumn = ({children}) => {
  const scroller = useRef(null)
  const scrollColumn = () => {
    let el = scroller.current;
    if (!el) return

    if (el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop === el.clientHeight) {
      el.scrollBy(0, -1);
    } else {
      el.scrollBy(0,1);
    }
  }

  useLayoutEffect(scrollColumn)

  return <div ref={scroller} className='scroll-container'>{children}</div>
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get('/data.json').then( res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({data: res.data}) 
    })

  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="table-responsive">
        <ScrollColumn>
          {
            this.state.data.map((item) => (
              <DataCard cardData={item} key={item.id} />
            ))
          }
        </ScrollColumn>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this out but nothing changed. There's no auto scrolling. Don't need to scroll when there's a child added, only need to scroll when the container is overflowed. Tried editing this a bit but ended up in infinite loops or my original error.

Comment: @BaileyCharlton this only runs when a child is added, which would affect your container size and thus run your scrollCode. Is this case it would only run twice: on first render and when the entire array of DataCard elements are placed. You shouldn't get an infinite loop unless you are still using setTimeout. Your function to calculate the container size and your css may need to change to work this way.

Comment: Here's an example of the above code in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wnixhq